# Find and update document where array size is less than value in field

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to find and update document where array size is less than field in this document?
Right now I solve this problem by maintaining field with array size and query like:

```golang
bson.M{"name": serviceName, "active": true, "$expr": bson.M{"$lt": bson.A{"$count", "$limit"}}}
```

Where `limit` is compared field and `count` it is a field with arrays size.

Comment: dont rly understand your question. you have one field with an array and another field with some number in it which you want to use as a threshhold? if you do so ou can query with $size https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/

Comment: $size allow to compare with constant like `{ $size: 2 }`. I want to compare with value in another field like `{ $expr: {$lt: {$array.size, $field_in_this_document_with_int_value }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{$expr: {$lt: [{$size: "$array"}, "$field_in_this_document_with_int_value"] }`

In `$expr` queries you can use any valid [aggregator expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions).